# Audio not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, soundcard

I installed ubuntu 12.04 some days ago. All works well, except audio, that's completely missing.

I tried several solutions, in particular modification of the file

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

I try to add this line at the and of file, and change the last value several time

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=3stack-dig

options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=generic

options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=6stack-dig

options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=auto
```

but nothing seems to work.

Output of `lspci | grep -i audio` is

```
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
```

Output of `aplay -l` is

```
**** List of PLAYBACK hardware devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevice: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevice: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output command `sudo lshw` appear both card, Nvidia and AMD

```
*-multimedia
          description: Audio device
          product: MCP61 High Definition Audio
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 5
          bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
          resources: irq:23 memory:fbff8000-fbffbfff

 *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0.1
             bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:fbdfc000-fbdfffff
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have both Nvidia and AMD appearing in the output of your command

```
lspci | grep -i audio
```

this is very suspect - do you really have two video cards from different manufacturers ?

Which of these appear in output of :

```
sudo lshw
```

ubuntu releases new versions every 6 months (12.04 was released month 4 of 2012) so 12.04 is 18 months old - I also experienced sound issues on earlier releases - ubuntu 13.10 seems fine.  You can always burn onto a CD/DVD a download of 13.10 to see of booting into ubuntu 13.10 from the CD gives you sound.  Alternatively, what do you get from simply going to your "System Settings" -> Sound -> Output to confirm you have selected valid settings.  Under the "Output" tab it lists available output transports.  Typically choose "Speakers built-in Audio"  also hit the "Test Sound" button where you can hit the front left or right test buttons to send a test tone into either speaker.

Comment: I add output for command `sudo lshw` in question. I checked in "System Settings" -> Sound -> Output" but seems to be everything right, but test sound doesn't work.